# how do i check if DateTime is null

Tags: c#, datetime, properties

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) is for string, but what is the code to check if Datetime is null?

```
    private DateTime? _ReleaseDate;

    public DateTime? ReleaseDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _ReleaseDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if ()
            {

            }
            else
            {
                _ReleaseDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `ValueType?` pattern is shorthand for [`Nullable<ValueType>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). In your case you have `Nullable<DateTime>`.

As you can see from the docs, `Nullable<ValueType>` implements a [`HasValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, so you can simply check it like so:

```
if (value.HasValue)
{

}
else
{

}
```

If you simply want to set a default value you can use the `GetValueOrDefault` method of `Nullable<T>` and do away with the if statement:

```
_ReleaseDate = value.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue); // or whatever default value you want.
```

Comment: @Michael I'm usually fast, you're usually detailed :)

Answer (score 2):

For *nullbale* types you can use `HasValue` or `!= null`

However for your example (with the code shown), you have more options

```
public DateTime? ReleaseDate
{
    get
    {
        return _ReleaseDate;
    }
    set
    {
        // if value is null, then that's all good, _ReleaseDate will be null as well
        _ReleaseDate = value; 
    }
}
```

Or

```
public DateTime? ReleaseDate {get;set}
```

The only reason you would need to do something like below, is when you have some specific behaviour on null or otherwise

```
public DateTime? ReleaseDate
{
    get
    {
        return _ReleaseDate;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            // has a value
        }
        else
        {
           // doesnt 
        }
    }
}
```